# Angular4 template driven form not working in Ionic Cordova android app

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have built a login form in Ionic3 app.

```
<div class="loginPageForm">
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.valid,f.value)">
      <div class="newFormControl">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" #Email="ngModel" ngModel required/>
      </div>
      <div class="newFormControl">
        <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" #Password="ngModel" ngModel required/>
      </div>
      <div class="newFormBtn">
        <input type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid" value="Sign In" />
      </div>
      <div class="loadingImgContainer" *ngIf="httpRequest">
        <img [src]="getLoadingimg()" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="newFormBtn">
        <p (click)='openForgetPasswordWindow()'>Forgot Password?</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

This is working fine in browser. But when I built it on android using Cordova. the submit button is always disabled. Even if I fill both the input box with proper values.

"@angular/forms": "5.0.3","ionic-angular": "3.9.2",

Comment: any errors in console when you run in device?

Comment: not getting any error

Comment: Can you add the ts file for this page?